# Exception handling with WCF Data Services

Tags: exception, wcf-data-services

I want to customize exceptions/errors thrown from my WCF Data Service, so clients get as much as possible information about what exactly went wrong/what is missing. Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 11):

There are a few things you need to do to ensure exceptions bubble over HTTP pipe to the client .

1. You must attribute your DataService class with the following:

   [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
   public class MyDataService : DataService
2. You must enable verbose errors in the configuration:

   public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }

It is best to throw [DataServiceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceexception.aspx) within. The WCF Data Service runtime knows how to map the properties to the HTTP response and will always wrap it in a [TargetInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx).

```
[WebGet]
public Entity OperationName(string id)
{
    try
    {
        //validate param
        Guid entityId;
        if (!Guid.TryParse(id, out entityId))
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to parse to type Guid", "id");

        //operation code
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        throw new DataServiceException(400, "Code", ex.Message, string.Empty, ex);
    }
}
```

You can then unpack this for the client consumer by overriding the HandleException in your DataService like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Unpack exceptions to the consumer
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args"></param>
protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs args)
{
    if ((args.Exception is TargetInvocationException) && args.Exception.InnerException != null)
    {
        if (args.Exception.InnerException is DataServiceException)
            args.Exception = args.Exception.InnerException as DataServiceException;
        else
            args.Exception = new DataServiceException(400, args.Exception.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2011/03/06/interesting-behavior-for-service-operation-exceptions.aspx) for more info...

Answer (score 3):

You can decorate your service class with this attribute ServiceBehaviorAttribute like so :

```
 [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
 public class PricingDataService : DataService<ObjectContext>, IDisposable
 {
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom exceptions for this.
Please read this post here: [Why Create Custom Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417428/why-create-custom-exceptions)

Which language are you developing in?

If you need further guidance, please add some comments.

Comment: I am developing in C#. However, the exceptions I throw from the service does not reach the clients consuming the service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he wants to know how to throw / catch exceptions in .NET.

He probably want to get thoughts on how to tell the clients consuming a WCF Data Service that something (and what) went wrong when an exception is being thrown / caught at the server(service) side.

WCF Data Services uses HTTP request / response messages and you can't just throw an exception from the service to the client.